# I want to apply same PCA to different datasets

Tags: pca, python

I am doing experiments in which I need to take different datasets. So, to make them consistent, I want to apply same PCA to all datasets failing which I can't compare them since, their offset will be different.
I can apply PCA on forst datasets by using
"PCA from sklearn.decompostion" in Python.
Now, my task is to apply same pca in subsequent datasets. How I can do that?
I can find the rotation angle from first PCA but how to apply subsequent PCAs by using that angle?
Note- I am doing this in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are working with Scikit-Learn, this should be fairly simple. Using the PCA decomposition class from sklearn, you will start by fitting your first dataset :

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_X1 = pca.fit_transform(dataset_1_X)
```

Using the `pca` instance that has just been fitted, you can then go on transforming your other datasets.

```
pca_X2 = pca.transform(dataset_2_X)
pca_X3 = pca.transform(dataset_3_X)
...
```

Note the use of **`pca.transform`** as opposed to `pca.fit_transform`. The former will use the components from the first dataset, whereas the latter will refit your other datasets.

Comment: Is there any way to track if first pca.fit_transform has already been used? Since the flow of execution of my program isn't fixed. So after first run, I want to fix the rotation angle and axis of pca.

Comment: @AkhilPratapSingh If you call `transform` on a PCA instance where `fit` or `fit_transform` has not been called, a `NotFittedError` will be raised. This means that if you can wrap a call to `pca.transform(np.zeros((1, 10)))` in a try/except block to check if it has been fitted.